# Swift slow on object creation and setValue:forKey:

Tags: swift

I am accessing a local MySQL database in Swift with code translated from Objective C. In Objective C it performs very fast, in Swift up to 10 to 15 times slower depending on the count of records.

I am using generics to create data transfer objects. The SQL select method has this signature:

```
func SQLSelect<T: NSObject>(select: String) -> [T]?
```

First I only fetched the 20.000 records from the MySQL database and returned early with an empty array of Ts. Time needed 0.3 seconds, which is not fast but acceptable.

Then I created 20.000 T instances in the above function and appended them to the local Swift array, which is fast: 0.1 sec.

Now creating 5 NSNumbers and 9 Strings from the fetched MySQL data is very slow: 1.2 sec. for 280.000 object creations (14 * 20.000 = 280.000). An additional 1.4 seconds is used for setting the properties of each T instance with setValue:ForKey:

The same code in Objective C and in Xojo (aka REALbasic) is fast: less than 1 second compared to more than 3 seconds.

What are my options to make the Swift code faster?

**First Edit – added the source code:**

```
func SQLSelect<T: NSObject>(select: String) -> [T]? {
  ... // error handling omitted
  var statement = select.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
  var err = mysql_real_query(mysql, statement, strlen(statement))
  ... // error handling omitted
  var mysql_result: UnsafeMutablePointer<MYSQL_RES> = mysql_store_result(mysql)
  ... // error handling omitted
  var mysql_fields: UnsafeMutablePointer<MYSQL_FIELD> = mysql_fetch_fields(mysql_result)
  ... // error handling omitted
  var names = [String]()
  var types = [UInt32]()
  var columnCount = mysql_num_fields(mysql_result)
  for i: Int in 0...columnCount - 1 {
    names.append(String.fromCString(mysql_fields[i].name)!)
    types.append(mysql_fields[i].type.value)
  }
  var records = [T]()
  var recordCount = Int(mysql_num_rows(mysql_result))
  records.reserveCapacity(recordCount - 1)
  for r in 0...recordCount - 1 {
    var row = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_result)
    var record = T()
    for c: Int in 0...columnCount - 1 {
        var value: AnyObject?
        if row[c] == nil {
          value = nil;
        } else {
          switch types[c] {
          case MYSQL_TYPE_TINY.value, MYSQL_TYPE_SHORT.value, MYSQL_TYPE_INT24.value, MYSQL_TYPE_LONG.value:
              value = NSNumber(int: atoi(row[c]))
          case MYSQL_TYPE_FLOAT.value:
              value = NSNumber(float: strtof(row[c], nil))
          ... // other data types omitted
          case MYSQL_TYPE_TINY_BLOB.value, MYSQL_TYPE_BLOB.value, MYSQL_TYPE_MEDIUM_BLOB.value, MYSQL_TYPE_LONG_BLOB.value, MYSQL_TYPE_BIT.value,
                 MYSQL_TYPE_SET.value, MYSQL_TYPE_ENUM.value, MYSQL_TYPE_GEOMETRY.value, MYSQL_TYPE_VAR_STRING.value, MYSQL_TYPE_STRING.value:
              if mysql_fields[c].charsetnr == 63 {
                value = NSData(bytes: row[c], length: Int(strlen(row[c])))
              } else {
                value = String.fromCString(row[c])!
              }
          case MYSQL_TYPE_NULL.value:
              value = nil
          default:
              value = nil
          }
          record.setValue(value, forKey: names[c])
        }
    }
    records.append(record)
  }
  return records
}
```

**Second Edit: results from running the code in Instruments**

It shows that approximately 40% of the time is spent in:

```
-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:]
```

and deeper in that function it is mainly these three functions:

```
@objc Swift._NSContiguousString.getCharacters (Swift._NSContiguousString)(Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.UInt16>, range : C._SwiftNSRange) -> ()
_swift_retain_(swift::HeapObject*)
_swift_release_(swift::HeapObject*)
```

The second biggest time use is in:

```
Swift.Array.append <A>(inout [A])(A) -> ()
```

So probably the only solution is to keep the access to the database in Objective C code.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code that you consider problematic?

Comment: Have tried compiling with `-O` and `-Ounchecked`?

Comment: @Pranav brings up an excellent point; more often than naught are such problems solved by a mere switch in the optimization settings.

Comment: No improvement by changing the compiler settings.

The slow parts are the object creation like:

value = NSNumber(int: atoi(row[c]))
value = NSNumber(float: strtof(row[c], nil))
value = String.fromCString(row[c])!

And setting the property of record:

record.setValue(value, forKey: names[c])